# How can i optimize this following mysql query

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

Can anyone tune this query for better performance ?

```
SELECT `Vocabulary`.`id`,
`Vocabulary`.`title`,
`Vocabulary`.`alias`,
`Vocabulary`.`description`,
`Vocabulary`.`required`,
`Vocabulary`.`multiple`,
`Vocabulary`.`tags`,
`Vocabulary`.`plugin`,
`Vocabulary`.`weight`,
`Vocabulary`.`updated`,
`Vocabulary`.`created`,
`TypesVocabulary`.`id`,
`TypesVocabulary`.`type_id`,
`TypesVocabulary`.`vocabulary_id`,
`TypesVocabulary`.`weight` 
FROM `epowerg`.`vocabularies` AS `Vocabulary` 
JOIN `epowerg`.`types_vocabularies` AS `TypesVocabulary` 
ON (`TypesVocabulary`.`type_id` IN (1, 2, 4) 
AND `TypesVocabulary`.`vocabulary_id` = `Vocabulary`.`id`)    
ORDER BY `Vocabulary`.`weight` ASC;
```

Result generated from query :

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Vocabulary      | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TypesVocabulary | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance 
Prabhakaran. R

Comment: Optimizing in what way?, do you have performance reasons?

Comment: Add an index to `type_id`

Comment: Why do you think it needs tuning?  It looks fine.

Comment: Also if you do want a good reply please post the expected table sizes for the 2 tables

Answer (score 3):

Here is the structure of your query:

```
select v.*, tv.*
from `epowerg`.`vocabularies` v JOIN
     `epowerg`.`types_vocabularies` tv
     ON tv.type_id IN (1, 2, 4) AND      
        tv.vocabulary_id = v.id    
ORDER BY v.weight ASC;
```

There are basically two possible execution plans for this query:  reading `v` first and looking up values in `tv`.  Or reading `tv` and looking up values in `v`.

For the first, you want indexes on `vocabularies(weight, id)` and `types_vocabularies(vocabulary_id, type_id)`.  If this works, then it will eliminate the sort.

The second approach to try is filtering on the types first.  The indexes for this are:  `types_vocabularies(type_id, vocabulary_id)` and `vocabularies(id)`.

Which method is better depends on the nature of your data.  But try the first first, because eliminating the sort is often a good idea.